# ngfor imprime desordenado

Tags: firebase, angular5

Tengo problemas con un chat que estoy haciendo con angular 5 y firebase, muestro los mensajes con el ngFor me los manda de manera random.

```
    <div class="alert alert-{{item.color}} mt-2" role="alert" *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{item.user}} dice: {{item.name}}
```

link del chat : https://tareas-dab28.firebaseapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El órden depende de como hayas "llenado" el arreglo, lo cual depende completamente del órden en la obtención especificado en tu origen de datos por algún elemento como alguna fecha o valor llave, como comentas que es Firebase, para RealTimeDb la referencia es aquí:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data (Cómo ordenar y filtrar datos)

o para FireStore aquí: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)